# Sublime Text 3 is automatically converting spaces to tabs on save, regardless of settings. How can I stop this?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm having trouble with Sublime Text 3.

Even if I select `View > Indentation > Convert tabs to spaces` and `View > Indentation > Indent using spaces` as soon as I save the file it all automatically gets converted to tabs.

How can I stop this behaviour from occurring?

I'm currently using default config settings for this:

```
// The number of spaces a tab is considered equal to
"tab_size": 4,

// Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,

// If translate_tabs_to_spaces is true, use_tab_stops will make tab and
// backspace insert/delete up to the next tabstop
"use_tab_stops": true,

// Set to false to disable detection of tabs vs. spaces on load
"detect_indentation": true,

// Calculates indentation automatically when pressing enter
"auto_indent": true,

// Makes auto indent a little smarter, e.g., by indenting the next line
// after an if statement in C. Requires auto_indent to be enabled.
"smart_indent": true,
```

Comment: In the right-bottom, did you select `indent using spaces` and `Tab Width` to 4? Or maybe some plugin is causing the issue. try disabling them.

Comment: I don't know what you mean be "right-bottom"? I've done as described in the question only.

Comment: http://sashabayanblog.azurewebsites.net/sizing-your-tabs-on-sublime-text-appropriately/

Comment: Had the same issue, turns out my `~/.editorconfig` file specified `indent_style = tab`, and I have the `EditorConfig` plugin installed.

Comment: Thanks for the thought Christof. I do have EditorConfig installed (not sure what it does!?) but my `~/.editorconfig` file is empty.

Comment: The way EditorConfig works is to look in the directory tree upwards for .editorconfig files. It will stop looking when a file specifies `root = true`. Perhaps there is such an `.editorconfig` file somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the `EditorConfig` plugin, when disabling it in PackageControl the problem went away.

Alternatively you can just edit the problematic `.editorconfig` file and just comment out (or set to false) the [`trim_trailing_whitespace`](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#trim_trailing_whitespace) option.

Comment: I had this same issue. Thanks for pointing me straight to the cause!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Use the indentation option under the tab View. 
You can select Tab Width:2

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to give up and switch to VSCode. I wasn't happy about it. I resisted. I cursed. But in the end I had to give in as it is way better. I spend far less time fiddling with editor config and more time coding.

Comment: LOL at whoever decided this answer was worth -1. How about I mark my own answer as accepted and cancel out your negativity :P

Answer (score -1):

You have two solutions:

1. To do "View > Indentation > Convert tabs to spaces" before saving
   the file.
2. To replace them as a normal text by pressing Ctrl + H. >>> Find all Tabs >>> Replace with 4 spaces